# Plot camera sensitivity-wavelength distribution based on RGB image

Tags: python, colors, histogram, rgb, spectrum

The following plot shows the normalized sensitivities of a camera RGB sensors (taken from a  [scientific publication](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Orit-Skorka/publication/336116765_Color_correction_for_RGB_sensors_with_dual-band_filters_for_in-cabin_imaging_applications/links/621be4896051a16582fd7e35/Color-correction-for-RGB-sensors-with-dual-band-filters-for-in-cabin-imaging-applications.pdf)):

[image]

These plots were generated by a raspberry pi device with a camera using [squareHSI software](https://osf.io/4z5s6). I want to create plots like these with python based on an RGB .jpg image. So far I couldn't find any python tool that is able to do something like that (Camera Sensitivity on Y axis and Wavelenght on X axis).

Tried using ChatGPT for help and plotted something like the following but I'm sure that's a wrong approach:

[image]

Any help? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: The RGB photos are captured through a 3D printed module that attaches onto a smartphone camera and has a diffraction grating.**

Comment: RGB do not have spectral information. AFAIK the camera uses tricks to get data using cheap sensors (so of a RBG camera) but I assume also with other optical tricks to split frequencies. Try to get a real (photo)spectrometer. Not so cheap, but the good: professionals usually pay for the software and services so the basic model may costs much less (and it is full capable, just use open source projects)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks for you fast reply! The RGB photos are captured through a 3D printed module that attaches onto a smartphone camera and has a diffraction grating. Don't know if that makes that different than what you said. Thanks anyway!

Comment: From a single person image and without knowing the spectrum of the irradiance source you won’t be able to find the sensitivities of the camera. You are mentioning a diffraction grating, do you have more information about it?

Comment: @KelSolaar thanks for your comment. The diffraction grating used in the module is the following: https://www.edmundoptics.eu/p/600-grooves-25mm-sq-287deg-blaze-angle-grating/10093/

Comment: Not sure why auto-complete added `single "person" image`, anyway, I suppose that you have lens to focus the incident rays? This is yet another component that you need to account the transmittance of. Without knowledge of the irradiance spectrum and the lens transmittance, there is an infinity of spectra that can produce the RGB values capture. With that in mind you cannot really find the exact sensitivities of the camera.